# How to match a string against an array of pattern in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I've two variables:

```
var input = "user1@gmail.com";
var preferredPatterns = ["*@gmail.com", "*@yahoo.com", "*@live.com"];
```

Want to match the input with preferred pattern array. If any of the patterns matches I've to do certain task (in this example, input is a definite match). How can I match against an array of pattern in javascript?

Comment: What kind of patterns are those? Those are not regular expressions.

Comment: how can I turn them into?

Comment: You need to take every and rewrite. Do you know regular expressions syntax?

Comment: Not to mention, `user1@gmail.com` is not a string, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `RegExp` constructor while passing a variable as regex.

```
var input = 'user1@gmail.com';
var preferredPatterns = [".*@gmail\\.com$", ".*@yahoo\\.com$", ".*@live\\.com$"];
for (i=0; i < preferredPatterns.length;i++) {
  if(input.match(RegExp(preferredPatterns[i]))) {
     console.log(preferredPatterns[i])
    }
    }
```

Dot is a special meta-character in regex which matches any character. You need to escape the dot in the regex to match a literal dot.

As @zerkms said, you could use the below list  of patterns also.

```
var preferredPatterns = ["@gmail\\.com$", "@yahoo\\.com$", "@live\\.com$"];
```

Comment: you mean that i need to give an exact pattern to match email id?

Comment: No, I mean that you can remove `.*` from regular expressions and nothing will change.

Comment: Use dot before star in your Regex. Please recheck the Regex I used.

Comment: .* will match all the characters including space. So we should use non space character \S i.e. ["\\S*@gmail\\.com", "\\S*@yahoo\\.com", "\\S*@live\\.com"]

Answer (score 9):

You can compile your patterns (if they are valid regular expressions) into one for performance:

```
var masterPattern = new RegExp(patterns.join('|'));
```

Putting it all together:

```
var input = 'user1@gmail.com';
var preferredPatterns = [
  ".*@gmail.com$",
  ".*@yahoo.com$",
  ".*@live.com$"
];

var masterPattern = new RegExp(preferredPatterns.join('|'));

console.log(masterPattern.test(input));
// true
```

Comment: That was not a part of the question. If you want that, you're better off going with @AvinashRaj's solution. This will only find whether or not any of the pattern matches, as per your original question, very very fast. (Handcrafting the `masterPattern` would be even faster, as you can refactor the `.* -- $` bit for more speed).

Comment: but this one shows 
`SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /*@qa-server5.com$|*@qa-server4.com$/`

Comment: "if they are valid regular expressions". Yours are not - there needs to be a period in front of the `*`. If you want to allow your users to input patterns, then you also need a method to transform them into valid regular expressions (escaping any dangerous characters, and turning `*` into `.*`, for starters). Otherwise, just write correct regular expression patterns in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Try this helper function:

```
/**
 * Returns an integer representing the number of items in the patterns 
 * array that contain the target string text
 */
function check(str, patterns) {
   return patterns.reduce(function (previous, current) {
      return previous + (str.indexOf(current) == -1 ? 0 : 1);
    }, 0);
}

check("user@gmail.com", ["@gmail.com", "@yahoo.com", "@live.com"]; // returns 1
check("user@live.com", ["@gmail.com", "@yahoo.com", "@live.com"]; // returns 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a general approach to matching against a list of regular expressions then some version of Avinash Raj's answer will work.

Based on the fact that you are specifying certain domains, you might want to match [any valid email address using the regex here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46181/4342563), and if it matches then check if the domain is a preferred one.  There are a number of different ways you could do that of course.  Here's just a simple example, splitting on the `@` and using `jQuery.inArray()` to check if the domain is preferred.

```
var preferredDomains = ["gmail.com", "yahoo.com", "live.com"];

function isValid(inputVal) {
    var re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;

    return re.test(inputVal) && $.inArray(inputVal.split('@')[1], preferredDomains) > -1;
}
```

The advantage here is that the underlying regex doesn't change, just the much easier to read/maintain list of domains.  You could tweak this to capture the domain in a group, instead of using split().

Answer (score 0):

```
preferredPatterns.forEach(function(element, index){ 
   if(input.match('/'+element) != null){ 
      console.log('matching  ' + element)  
   }
})
```

you  can write your custom logic if a string matches any pattern.

Answer (score 0):

No regexp you may do as follows;

```js
function matchPattern(xs, [y,...ys]){
  
  function helper([x,...xs]){
    return "*" + xs.join('') === y ? true
                                   : xs.length ? helper(xs)
                                               : false;
  }
  
  return helper(xs) ? y
                    : ys.length ? matchPattern(xs,ys)
                                : "No Match..!";
}

var input             = "user1@gmail.com",
    preferredPatterns = ["*@yahoo.com", "*@live.com", "*@gmail.com"];
    result            = matchPattern(input, preferredPatterns);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -2):

You may iterate through array and then use regex to compare with individual items.